# How to get ORDERED Result for a Derived Table result set using ROWID in SQL Plus?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a `emp` table as follows

```
empnum deptno salary
----- ------ ------
1      null    null
null   2       null
null   null    null
null   null    3
5      null    4
null   6       1
```

I want the result set should be like

```
result
------
1
2
0
3
5
4
6
1
```

If there are `3 nulls` it should display `0`,
if there is `only one null` it should display 
the other two values in the same sequence in which they were inserted,
if there are '2 nulls' then it should display the one value in result set.

I have tried

```
select rs from  
((select decode(empno||deptno||sal,null,0,substr(empno||deptno||sal,1,1)as rs,rowid as ri from emp)
union  
((select decode(empno||deptno||sal,null,0,substr(empno||deptno||sal,2,1)as rs,rowid as ri from emp)  
minus  
(select decode(empno||deptno||sal,null,0,substr(empno||deptno||sal,1,1)as rs,rowid as ri from emp)))  
where rs is not null  
order by ri,rs;
```

the above query gives result as

```
rs
--
1
2
0
3
4
5
1
6
```

can any one help me out in getting the exact result set as mentioned above.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: A heap organized table is inherently unordered.  How do you know what order the rows were inserted?  Is there an additional column (i.e. a `DATE` or a `TIMESTAMP`) that isn't in your example that tells you when the row was inserted?  A `ROWID` is a physical address, it has no relationship to the order in which rows were inserted.

Comment: If there's no timestamp, oracle does provide the `ROWSCN` pseudocolumn which can tell you the last time the block that this row is in was modified. If you haven't ever updated the table, you might be able to use this to get *some* idea of the order, but not a very good one.

Comment: @JustinCave  I know that ROWID doesn't has any physical relation with the order in which records were inserted but we can order the result set using rowid as i have done above .

Comment: You need a timestamp on the record to know for certain when it was inserted...

Comment: Here above i am not using any 'timestamp' so the record holding the values '4 null 5' is having the same rowid for both 4 and 5 i mean 'empno' and 'sal' 
So can there be a solution to overcome this problem ?

Comment: @Aspirant - Yes, you can order by `ROWID`.  That is not meaningful-- it certainly doesn't guarantee that you'll get the rows that were inserted first to be first in the result set or that the order of rows will be fixed over time.  How do you determine that `5` comes before `4` and `6` comes before `1` by just looking at the data?

Comment: @Aspirant - What is the problem you are trying to solve with this result set? SQL isn't really a good approach for this. Your data has no "key" row nor "inserted date" row. You are attempting to pivot the data out to get a result set where the number of values depends on the data itself, and SQL pivots are frustrating at best..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is HIGHLY dependent on how your table was created. It needs to be created with ROWDEPENDENCIES, and there needs to be a COMMIT after each insert to ensure that order maintained.

This is likely not useful with real-world data. If you didn't store a time stamp in your table for the insert time of the record, there is NO WAY to determine the order of the column.

With sample table and data:

```
create table emp
(empnum int, deptno int, salary int) ROWDEPENDENCIES;
insert into emp (empnum, deptno, salary) values
(1,      null,    null); 
commit;
insert into emp (empnum, deptno, salary) values
(null,   2,       null);
commit;
insert into emp (empnum, deptno, salary) values
(null,   null  ,  null); 
commit;
insert into emp (empnum, deptno, salary) values
(null ,  null ,   3); 
commit;
insert into emp (empnum, deptno, salary) values
(5     , null,    4);
commit;
insert into emp (empnum, deptno, salary) values
(null   ,6 ,      1  ); 
commit;

create table emp2
(empnum int, deptno int, salary int, rowscn int) ROWDEPENDENCIES;
insert into emp2
select empnum, deptno, salary, ora_rowscn from emp;
```

You can then use the `ORA_ROWSCN` pseudocolumn to determine the insert date:

```
with countqry as
(select empnum, deptno, salary, 
        rowscn,
        decode(empnum, null, 0, 1) e,
        decode(deptno, null, 0, 1) d,
        decode(salary, null, 0, 1) s    
from emp2)
select 0 as val, rowscn 
from countqry where e+d+s = 0
union  all
select coalesce(empnum, deptno, salary) as val, 
       rowscn
from countqry where e+d+s = 1
union all 
select val, rowscn from
(
select * from 
  (select empnum, deptno, salary, rowscn 
    from countqry where e+d+s >= 2)
unpivot (val for x in (empnum as '1', deptno as '2', salary as '3'))
order by rowscn, val
)
order by rowscn
```

[Here is a working example on SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/427cc/10)

Comment: Also, you didn't specify how the pivoted columns should be ordered, but it appears they are ordered by the value itself, so that's the way I did it.